# Android studio Emulator not closing

Tags: android, android-studio

I've opened my emulator from android studio after few hrs i'm trying to close that but it's not closing and i can't shutdown my mac too.
I've tried to quite options and close button but still not emulator not closing.

Comment: Try the "stop" option provided by AVD Manager, as suggest by @Kan. In case, that option is grayed out try this: From Apple Icon on top left —> Select “Force Quite” option —> Select the running emulator from the list —> Select “Force Quit”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the AVD manager to close that.
Just open the AVD manager -> select the emulator currently run, there is an option to stopping your emulator. it's worked for me